# Missing required parameters for route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

in my laravel application whenever i go to this route:  /admin or admin/users I get the following error message but the the other routes work like admin/users/create or admin/users/edit:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.users.edit] [URI: admin/users/{id}/edit]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)
```

To note I'm not including all the html code of index.blade.php as it's too long the only blade code is from what i have pasted.

Index.blade view:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{route('admin.users.edit')}}">All Userss</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{route('admin.users.create')}}">Create User</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
```

Route list:

URI:

```
- admin/users
- admin/users/create
- admin/users/store
- admin/users/update
- admin/users/{id}/edit
```

Name:

```
1. admin.users.index
 2. admin.users.create
 3. admin.users.store
 4. admin.users.update
 5. admin.users.edit
```

Action:

```
 1. App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@index 
 2. App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@create 
 3. App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@store 
 4. App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@update 
 5. App\Http\Controllers\AdminUsersController@edit
```

admin/users

Routes:

```
Route::get('admin/users/', [

    'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@index',
    'as' => 'admin.users.index'
]);


Route::get('admin/users/create', [

    'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@create',
    'as' => 'admin.users.create'
]);

Route::get('admin/users/{id}/edit', [

    'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@edit',
    'as' => 'admin.users.edit'
]);
```

Controller:

```
    public function edit($id)
    {

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user', 'roles'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
```

Edit View:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')

<h1>Edit Users</h1>

{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['AdminUsersController@update', $user->id], 'files' => true]) !!}

@include('includes.form-error')

<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

</div>


<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
    {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

</div>


<div class="form-group">

<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('role_id',$roles , null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

</div>

<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('status', 'Status:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('status', [1 => 'Active', 0 => 'Not Active'], 0, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

</div>

    <div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('photo_id', 'Photo:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('photo_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

</div>


<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::label('password', 'Password:') !!}
    {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

</div>

<div class="form-group">

    {!! Form::submit('Create User', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

</div>


{!! Form::close() !!}


@endsection
```

Comment: Have u tried to delete backslash from `Route::get('admin/users/'`to make it like so: `Route::get('admin/users'` ?

Comment: I did that and now i get the following error message: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\resources\views\admin\users\index.blade.php)

Comment: Be sure you show all the routes file and try to execute `php artisan route:clear` and then post results of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Edit your question and post results there

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius Updated my question with the route list.

Comment: And the index.blade.php please :)

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius what you mean - view? or controller?

Comment: The view (index.blade.php)

Comment: Done it. It's probably something silly.

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius I mean I updated my post for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your error. You missed to pass the variable in route:

```
  <li>
      <a href="{{route('admin.users.edit')}}">All Users</a>
  </li>
```

Instead of `{{route('admin.users.edit')}}` use:

`{{route('admin.users.edit', $id)}}`

This is actually editing route. If you want to get all users use:

`{{route('admin.users.index')}}`

Comment: Now i get Undefined variable: id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)

Comment: Because, you don't have a `$id` variable. Just replace it with `{{route('admin.users.index')}}`. `$id` will be used when you are going to edit  selected user.

Comment: Right that works. But with /admin/users i get this error: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\resources\views\admin\users\index.blade.php)

Comment: there should not be any `$id` in `/admin/users`. You put somewhere `$id`, just remove it

Answer (score 3):

Change `{{route('admin.users.edit')}}` to `{{route('admin.users.edit', $id)}}` and dont forget to change `$id` to the real id variable  :)

And its strange, because you write `All users` and giving the edit route :)

Comment: Now i get : Undefined variable: id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\resources\views\admin\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
<a href="{{route('admin.users.edit')}}">All Userss</a>
```

in your Blade file, but your route is defined like so:

```
Route::get('admin/users/{id}/edit', [

    'uses' => 'AdminUsersController@edit',
    'as' => 'admin.users.edit'
]);
```

so it's edit action and you need to pas id of user you want to edit for example:

```
<a href="{{route('admin.users.edit', [auth()->user()->id])}}">All Userss</a>
```

Comment: In case you have more than one parameter in your route, `eg. /{class_id}/{episode_id}` this answer is the one, because of that array notation.